# Teenage boy who witnesses the murder of his neighbor

Tags: identify-this-movie, crime

I'm new here. I'm french so in advance sorry if I make mistakes.

Since a very long time ago, I search a TV movie not very well-known that I watched in my youth. It's a similar movie from *Rear Window* by Alfred Hitchcock  and *Disturbia* with Shia Labeouf but it's not these movies.

It's about a teenage boy obliged to stay at home and who witnesses the neighbor's murder of his redheaded wife.

It's a little blurry in my memory, but I think that he warns his mother and they call the police. However, when the police come, the woman is still alive.

During the movie, with his friend and a girl that he loves they will do their investigation. I remember that the girl often climbs in the witness-boy's room by the window. They flirt together. The witnessing boy will enter in the neighbor house while his two friends will distract the neighbor.

If I remember correctly, they use a walkie-talkie. At the end, they learn that the neighbor has indeed killed his wife and the reason that his wife was still alive was because the sister of the murdered woman had replaced her.

It was a plot between the husband and the sister of the murdered woman.

At the end, the boy is allowed to go out. On a baseball field, he finds again the girl that he loves and who helped him, they kiss and it's the end.

Comment: Welcome to Movies & TV! Please try to add anything that may help identification. When was it released? Was it in Color or Black & White? What time period was it showing? What country was it likely from or what language was it in? Descriptions or names of characters or actors you can give? Anything at all? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question. For help writing a good identification question, see: [**Identify-This-X Questions**](http://movies.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 6):

Sounds like "[The Darklings](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0186019/)" from 1999

> "The fact that Tippi Hedren is cast as the grandmother of the protagonist is hardly the only Hitchcock reference in the made-for-cable thriller The Darklings. While bedridden with a case of mono, teenager C.J. (Ryan DeBoer) glances out his window, and sees--or thinks he sees--next-door neighbor Clayton Shepherd (Timothy Busfield) murdering his wife Emily (Suzanne Somers). Of course, when the authorities are summoned, there is no evidence of any murder--and in fact there's no body. Further developments suggest that C.J. was simply imagining things, but he refuses to accept this explanation. In league with his youthful pals Jessie (Meghan Ory) and Josh (Ben Johnson), C.J. is determined to bend and even break the law to prove that Shepherd is a killer. Martin Sheen also stars in this delightful blend of TV-style teen angst, light humor and dastardly deeds. The Darklings premiered February 14, 1999 on the Fox Family channel."

The girl who is the boy's friend does climb through his window. I remember watching it on TV when I was young.

I was unable to find a trailer of the movie, but did find a clip of it:

Answer (score -1):

Could you be thinking of *[Disturbia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disturbia_(film))* (2007)?

> [After his father is killed](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0486822/plotsummary) in a car accident, things unravel for Kale Brecht and he is placed under house-arrest for punching his Spanish teacher. Having nothing better to do, Kale occupies himself by spying on his neighbors. But one night, he witnesses what appears to be a murder going on in Mr. Turner's house. Kale becomes obsessed with uncovering the truth behind these murders but, after a few unsettling run-ins with Mr. Turner, it becomes a matter of life and death. And the ominous question: Who is watching whom?

Comment: The original post says:  "...and **Disturbia** with Shia Labeouf **but it's not these movies**."

Comment: Hahaha, missed that.

Comment: No big deal, you can delete this answer if you'd like, I've had to do the same in the past.